# How to enforce a local branch name to start with 2019.06.0

Tags: git

In the project Release branches like 2019.06.0 are open to developers to create their local branches and work on it .Now I need all the branches that are branching out from release/2019.06.0 branch to start with 2019.06.0_ .I am trying to enforce a naming standard when a developer tries to es to do git checkout -b .
Customscripts are not enabled .What is the best way to accomplish this in git ?Any such hooks or rules exit ?

New to git .None of the existing ideas helped me on this

Comment: Sounds like you want a pre-receive hook to validate the name of each ref

Comment: Why do you care what names I use on *my* computer? So what if I want to call the branch `frabblenitzer`? You should worry only about the names I give to *you*.

Comment: You don't want to enforce the naming policy when the developer does `git checkout -b`, because you don't (shouldn't) care about the names they use locally.  You only care about the names they try to push.

Comment: I don't get this. You want to control what anyone in the world can do with a clone of your repository?

Answer (score 1):

I won't vouch for the completeness of this solution (indeed, I will argue that it is incomplete), but for a simple validation you might try this simple pre-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '$3 ~ /^refs\/heads/ && ! $3 ~ /^refs\/heads\/2019.06.0/ {
        print "Invalid branch name: " $3 > "/dev/stderr";  
        exit 1
}'
```

Add that file to `.git/hooks/pre-receive` and make it executable.  When anyone attempts to push to your repo, it will fail if they try to push a branch that doesn't match your desired naming convention.